# convert a number to uint24 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography

How do I convert a number (int) into uint24 in python3?

```
num = 196458

num_uint24 = ?
```

Comment: what is a uint24 and why do you think it needs conversion?

Comment: I'm trying to access ticks() method from https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/core/interfaces/pool/IUniswapV3PoolState; the ticks() method accepts the tickID as uint24